# derivative of a function of a vector

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, vectors

I'm not familiar with the derivative of a function of a vector. I know that $\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}=2\mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is a n*1 vector.

However, for a more complicated case, $f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x})(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\mathbf{B}_i^T\mathbf{x})}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}}$, where $\mathbf{a}$ is a n*1 vector, $\mathbf{B}_i$ is the i-th column of a n*n matrix, and $\mathbf{1}$ is a n*1 vector of which all entries are 1. What does $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial\mathbf{x}}$ look like?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
The sum in your expression is a quadratic form:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\mathbf{B}_{i}^{T}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}$.
The derivative of this quadratic with respect to $\mathbf{x}$ is 
$$
\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}\left(\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}\right)
=
\mathbf{B}^{T}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}.
$$
(By the way, this is the same formula used to compute the derivative of $\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{x}$).

Can you use the product rule to find the derivative of the entire expression?

Comment: Hi, given $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{B}^T$, I can write $f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{B}\mathbf{xx}^T\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}}$. How to get the derivative into a column vector form? thanks.